# Outputting to SH1106 display with PIL only works from loaded files

Tags: python-3, spi

I'm dealing with a maddening bug when trying to use an OLED module (sh1106 clone, interfaced over SPI) with a raspberry pi. I have stolen the following function from https://github.com/8TN/Raspberry-Pi-SH1106-oled-display, and modified the pins used slightly.

```
# setup...

def display_img(image):
    data_slice=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    GPIO.output(A0, 0)
    pixels = image.load()
    for p in range (0,8): #l'image est découpée en 8 tranches horizontales de 8 pixels
        data_set = []
        for c in range (0,128): #chaque tranche fait 8x128 px
            by = 0x00
            for b in range (0,8):
                by = by>>1 | (pixels[c, p*8+b]& 0x80)
            data_set.append(by)
        data_slice[p]=data_set
    spi.xfer([0xAF]) #active l'afficheur (0xAE pour l'éteindre)
    for p in range (0,8):
        GPIO.output(A0, 0)
        spi.xfer([0xB0+p, 0x02, 0x10]) #initialise l'adresse des colonnes
        GPIO.output(A0, 1)
        spi.xfer(data_slice[p]) #transfer 1 tranche de 128x8 pixels
```

This code, as expected, displays "h1234" on the screen:

```
canvas = Image.new('1', (128,64),0)
brush = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
brush.text((64,32),"h1234",fill=1)
print(canvas.size)
canvas.save("test.png")
img = Image.open("test.png")
display_img(img)
# displays h1234 on the screen
```

but, for some reason, loading the PIL image directly displays a black screen:

```
canvas = Image.new('1', (128,64),0)
brush = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
brush.text((64,32),"h1234",fill=1)
print(canvas.size)
canvas.save("test.png")
img = Image.open("test.png")
display_img(canvas)
# black screen, test.png still has the right form
```

Any idea what it responsible for this?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue of me misunderstanding PIL. The problem was that the `"1"` image mode encodes white as `0x01`, while (confusingly) the version obtained by default loading encodes white as `0xff`. The display code filters out the `0x80` bit to only color in pixels based on the MSB.